# PHP OOP calling private function as callback in create_function

Tags: php, oop

I have created a class extending SimpleXMLElement which loads an XML containing translations for a multilingual website.
In this class are two private functions - get and translate.
The former returns the translation contained in the node accessed by the xpath passed as an argument.
The latter replaces tag-like substrings in a string (eg. "Lorem ipsum #{dolor} sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.") with their translation obtained via 
the former function - the tag being a sort of xpath I process in my get() function.
I'm using preg_replace_callback in translate() - for I cannot pass a back reference as an argument to a function in preg_replace - to send matched occurrences to get(), which will replace them with the translation.

Here is a shortened version of my class :

```
$translation = new Translation('path_to_my_xml', null, true);

class Translation extends SimpleXMLElement {
    function get($xpath){
        // xpath is of the form 'parent_node/child_node'
        // After some processing and the wanted node being found - it returns the translation
    }

    function translate($string){
        $string = preg_replace_callback('/#\{([a-z0-9-\/]+)\}/', create_function('$matches', 'return $this->get($matches[1]);'), $string);
    }
}
```

Of course, I get a fatal error : using $this when not in object context, for the class hasn't been instantiated in my create_function call - I tried `self::get($matches[1])` as well without success.
These functions cannot be public for my class being an extension of SimpleXMLElement, it requires the path to an XML in the constructor.
So I can't do this : `create_function('$matches', 'return Translation::get($matches[1]);')`.
I hope I made myself clear. The only workaround I see is passing the path to my XML in my translate() function and make it public, but this would be very inconvenient.
Do you see any other way out ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hang on, can't you just use an old style array PHP callback like this?

```
function translate($string){
    $string = preg_replace_callback('/#\{([a-z0-9-\/]+)\}/', 
                                    array($this, 'translateCallback'), 
                                    $string);
}

public function translateCallback($matches)
{
  return return $this->get($matches[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, it works perfectly. Just why do it the easy way when you can do it the hard way, humm ? I just didn't know you could use an array as a callback.

Answer (score 2):

1:

```
preg_replace_callback($regexp, array($this, 'someMethod'), $string)
```

2:

```
$myFunc = function($matches) use ($this) ...
...
preg_replace_callback('/#\{([a-z0-9-\/]+)\}/', $myFunc, $string)
```

3: 
Override __construct in Translation to save last instance, implement Translation::getLastInstance() and use it inside create_function or implement Translation::get($m) that use last instance and pass it to preg_replace_callback as array('Translation', 'get'), or just save before preg_replace_callback link to current instance to self::$currentInstance.
In any case the sence is in saving a link to the instance into static property of Translation

Answer (score 0):

The facility to use $this in lambda/anonymous functions was added in PHP 5.4, suspect this is similar; but I'd have to run up my testbed to check.

You could try:

```
$string = preg_replace_callback('/#\{([a-z0-9-\/]+)\}/', function($matches) use ($this) { return $this->get($matches[1]); }, $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not terribly helpful, but in PHP 5.4 anonymous functions can access `$this`.  When's your ship date?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm running on PHP 5.2.